# How to play audio file with AndroidAudioPlayer from TrasosDSP-android.jar?

Tags: android

I am trying the app for speech synthesis by using some DSP approach. Fortunately, the TrasosDSP supports most of these approaches for android.[TrasosDSP for Android](https://0110.be/tags/TarsosDSP?fbclid=IwAR2DhvxBSXcfg6yQ37yhleMSUs1O4tyyHa9YgayZBW1EEgylf2DdRSYb3ec). But I cannot play audio with AndroidAudioPlayer in TrasosDSP although I tested according to their sample code. I cannot able to trace it is why? Here is the sample code from [TrasosDSP for Android](https://0110.be/tags/TarsosDSP?fbclid=IwAR2DhvxBSXcfg6yQ37yhleMSUs1O4tyyHa9YgayZBW1EEgylf2DdRSYb3ec).

With the TarsosDSP Android library the following code plays an MP3 from external storage:

```
new AndroidFFMPEGLocator(this);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File mp3 = new File(externalStorage.getAbsolutePath()   , "/audio.mp3");
    AudioDispatcher adp;
    adp = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromPipe(mp3.getAbsolutePath(),44100,5000,2500);
    adp.addAudioProcessor(new AndroidAudioPlayer(adp.getFormat(),5000, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    adp.run();
  }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your music is in the Music folder, try replacing:

```
File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File mp3 = new File(externalStorage.getAbsolutePath()   , "/audio.mp3");
```

with

```
File mp3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Music/audio.mp3");
```

For some reason this way it works, but it took me 2 weeks of puzzling.